# How to find the location for a start up program located in task manager win10

Tags: windows-10, virus, updates

In Windows 10 with all other startup programs, I can right click on them and have the option to view file location.  I have two startup programs called "update" and neither of them show their file location (grayed out and non-selectable)?

I thought it was just a registry error at first, but now another device on my network has the same "update" startup programs.  Recently the other user also installed MS office 2016 free student edition. So maybe its associated?  Though, her device also has another startup program called "program" with no other description either and her device is running very slow and showing signs of a breech.

When the desktop loads 3 black cmd windows pop up for a second. Nothing new in her programs list though and no positive correlation in task man to a process with high usage.

[image]

Comment: If you right click on the column headers, you can turn on a few columns that aren't visible by default. If the "Command Line" field is populated for that item, it should point you to the location.

Answer (score 4):

So, task manager>startup than on the upper row right click on "name" and click on "Command line" to show the file path aka file location.

[image]

Comment: In addition I will have to go to the registry to remove said files.  I will also look under "run once" to try to find those cmd windows that load at start up too. Since I already checked msconfig and nothing foreign is there.

Comment: Use a program like Autoruns, makes your job easier, instead of trying to find it yourself within the registry editor.  However, how you remove the startup entry, would be its own question and answer.